# Is there a more efficient way to grab multiple minimum values in an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filtering, key-value

I have a solution for this but I'm not sure if it's the best way .. I have an object that looks like this:

```
const obj = {
  thingA: 1,
  thingB: 2,
  thingC: 1,
  thingD: 1,
  thingE: 4
}
```

I'd like to grab all the key value pairs that have the lowest value and then be able to randomly select one of the key value pairs with the lowest value (in this case randomly select one key out of the three that have 1 as the value).

This is what I have and this works but I was wondering if there's a way that's better/more efficient:

```
const keyArray = Object.keys(obj)
const minArray = (keyArray) => {
  const min = keyArray.reduce((prev, curr) => obj[curr] ? prev : curr); 

  const res = [];
    for (const key of keyArray) {
      if (obj[key] !== obj[min]) {
       continue
      } 
     res.push(key)
   }
 return res
}

const randomMinKey = minArray(keyArray)[Math.floor(Math.random()*minArray.length)]
```

Comment: `const min = Math.min(...Object.values(obj)); const minPairs = Object.entries(obj).filter(([, v]) => v === min); const randomMinKey = minPairs[Math.floor(Math.random()*minPairs.length)];` btw i am not fully sure what "efficient" means in this case, but i assumed "less code, potentually easier to read"

Comment: Haha. Funny how you tried to hide so much the true purpose of this algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One loop, in comparison to looping by reduce and then through the object keys.

```js
const obj = {
  thingA: 1,
  thingB: 2,
  thingC: 1,
  thingD: 1,
  thingE: 4
}

function randomizeKey(_obj) {
  let objKeysArr = [];
  let minValue;

  for (const property in _obj) {
    if (minValue == undefined || _obj[property] < minValue) {
      objKeysArr = [];
      minValue = _obj[property];
    }

    if (_obj[property] == minValue) {
      objKeysArr.push(property);
    }
  }

  console.log(`all keys: ${objKeysArr}`);

  return objKeysArr[randomize(objKeysArr.length)];
}

function randomize(max, min) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + (min || 0);
}

console.log( randomizeKey(obj) );
```

Answer (score 1):

only one loop for everything !
and only one direct assignation ;)

it also build the array of keys in one action, without calculate first the minimal value, and then filter all elements with this key.

```js
const obj = { thingA: 1, thingB: 2, thingC: 1, thingD: 1, thingE: 4 }

let rand = Object.entries(obj).reduceRight((a,[k,v],idx)=>
  {
  if (v < a.min)   { a.min = v;  a.res.length = 0 }
  if (v === a.min) { a.res.push(k) }
  if (idx) return a
  else     return a.res[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.res.length)]
  },{ min:Infinity, res:[] } )

console.log( rand )
```